# Implementing certain methods in a BST class

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

Consider the following definitions of BSTNode and BST classes:

```
public class BSTNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
 protected T el;
 protected BSTNode<T> left, right;
 public BSTNode() {
 left = right = null;
 }
 public BSTNode(T el) {
 this(el,null,null);
 }
 public BSTNode(T el, BSTNode<T> lt, BSTNode<T> rt) {
 this.el = el; left = lt; right = rt;
 }
}
public class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
 protected BSTNode<T> root = null;
 public BST() {
 }
….
}
```

how can i implement a method in class BST to count the number of right children in a BST

Comment: Hey Rakan, what is your question? SO is not a place where you ask others to do your homeworks, it's rather a place where you ask a specific question. You shoud do your own research and try something. Explain here what you tried and why it didn't work and specifically what didn't work.

Comment: how can i edit the post ?

Comment: There's an edit link right under the question on the left, under the tags. Next to share

Comment: Done. can someone help me now ?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my comment, you should look for a solution by yourself and ask specific questions here. If you don't know where to start, just google "binary search tree java" and you'll find plenty of resources to help you start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, the number of right children of a node can be counted recursively as follows.

First, implement a recursive method in the `BSTNode` class.

```
public int GetNumOfRightChildren()
{
    int Result = 0;
    if (null != right)
        Result = 1 + right.GetNumOfRightChildren();
    return Result;

}
```

Next, this method could be made accessible in a very similar way in the `BST` class as follows.

```
public int GetNumOfRightChildren()
{
    int Result = 0;
    if (null != root)
        Result = 1 + root.GetNumOfRightChildren();
    return Result;
}
```

If changing the implementation of `BSTNode` is not permitted, the task cannot be solved as the right and left subtrees in `BSTNode` are inaccessible from the `BST` class.